# Given a convex polygon with integer coordinates vertices, how can you transform it so you can always find a point inside it with integer coordinates?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, polygons

Given a convex polygon, with all its vertices having integer coordinates, you are allowed to perform one transformation T to all of its vertices (which are points), such that:

- T transforms a point in another (possibly the same) point.
- If P is a point with integer coordinates, T(P) will be a point with integer coordinates.
- Let `u`, `v` be two consecutive vertices of the original polygon. If a point P was originally on the edge `{u, v}` of the original polygon, T(P) will be a point that is on the edge `{T(u), T(v)}` of the transformed polygon.
- If a point P was originally *in the interior* of the original polygon, T(P) will be a point that is *in the interior* of the transformed polygon.
- If a point P was originally *outside* the original polygon, T(P) will be a point that is *outside* the transformed polygon.

After applying the transformation T to the polygon, you must find a point Q *in the interior* the transformed polygon with integer coordinates.

- Notice that Q must **not** be on an edge of the transformed polygon, but strictly *in the interior* of it.

You may assume that:

- We are working in 2D.
- No two vertices of the original polygon are the same.
- No three consecutive vertices of the original polygon are collinear.

I'm interested in finding a transformation T that satisfies those conditions for all polygons with vertices with integer coordinates, and a way to generate a point with integer coordinates in the interior of the transformed polygon.

Some observations I've come to, but couldn't prove:

It appears that all convex polygons with integer coordinates vertices such that

1. The *maximum Y* of any of its points minus the *minimum Y* of any of its points is 1; or
2. The *maximum X* of any of its points minus the *minimum X* of any of its points is 1

will yield no points with integer coordinates in the interior of them.

One particular example is the triangle formed by `{0, 0}`, `{0, 1}`, `{1, 0}`.

[Triangle of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5HDI.png)

- For this case, notice that any of the following transformations will still yield a polygon with no integer coordinates points inside of it:

  1. (x, y) -> (2x, y)
     [Transformation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAyPO.png)
  2. (x, y) -> (x, 2y)
     [Transformation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWtcV.png)
  3. (x, y) -> (2x, 2y)
     [Transformation 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU4VA.png)
- But the following transformations will:

  1. (x, y) -> (-3x, -3y)
     [Transformation 1A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drlIm.png)
  2. (x, y) -> (6x, 4y)
     [Transformation 2A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGq14.png)

Comment: There some obvious ones, such as (x, y) -> (2x, y). (unless I have misunderstood the question) What have you tried?

Comment: @Peter That one doesn't work if the given polygon is `{0, 0}`, `{1, 0}`, `{0, 1}`. It would give `{0, 0}`, `{2, 0}`, `{0, 1}` which is a polygon with no points with integer coordinates inside of it.

Comment: In that case, what about (x, y) -> (2x, 2y)?

Comment: @Peter Actually, it still doesn't work. `{0, 0}`, `{2, 0}`, `{0, 2}` is also a polygon with no points with integer coordinates inside of it. Just to be clear, even if the given transformation would generate points with integer coordinates inside the polygon, it would still be necessary to find a way to find at least one of those points.

Comment: Please edit the question, with examples, to make it clearer. Note, "inside" should perhaps be "in the interior".

Comment: @Peter I edited it following your suggestion. Also I added some of my tries and examples with images.

Comment: What are the conditions on $T$? Is it linear?

Comment: @BrianTung T is not necessarily linear. If we assume a point P could be written as a pair of coordinates `{x, y}`, then `T({x,y})` should output `{x', y'}` such that `{x', y'}` is a point in 2D space.

Comment: @BrianTung However, finding a linear transformation *T'* along with a way to find a point with integer coordinates in the interior of the polygon transformed by *T'* would suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The transformation $T(x,y) = (3x,3y)$ always works.

Here's why. Let $A = (x_0, y_0)$, $B = (x_1, y_1)$, and $C = (x_2, y_2)$ be three vertices of the polygon. Then their centroid $G = (\frac{x_0+x_1+x_2}{3}, \frac{y_0 + y_1 + y_2}{3})$ is in the interior of $\triangle ABC$, and therefore in the interior of the polygon.

The linear transformation has all the nice properties we want, and in particular it preserves interiors. So we know that $T(G)$ is in the interior of the transformed polygon.

But it's also true that $T(G)$ has integer coordinates: more precisely, the integer coordinates $(x_0 + x_1 + x_2, y_0 + y_1 + y_2)$.

---

In fact, as long as the polygon is not a triangle, the transformation $T(x,y) = (2x,2y)$ will work. For this, let $A = (x_0, y_0)$ and $B = (x_1, y_1)$ be two vertices of the polygon that are *not* adjacent. Then the midpoint of $AB$, the point $M = (\frac{x_0 + x_1}{2}, \frac{y_0 + y_1}{2})$, is in the interior of the polygon, and by a similar argument as for the previous transformation, $T(M) = (x_0 + x_1, y_0 + y_1)$ is an integer point inside the transformed polygon.